# how to split this kind of column in a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have data frame same like below:

```
  Name          Rating          Review     Price
1  The park     NaN             NaN        5040
2  The Westin   Good 7.6        NaN        6045
3  Courtyard    NaN             NaN        4850
4  Radisson     Excellent 9.8   NaN        7050
5  Banjara      Average 6.7     NaN        5820
6  Mindspace    NaN             NaN        8000
```

My required output is like this:

```
  Name         Review          Rating     Price
1  The park     NaN             NaN        5040
2  The Westin   Good            7.6        6045
3  Courtyard    NaN             NaN        4850
4  Radisson     Excellent       9.8        7050
5  Banjara      Average         6.7        5820
6  Mindspace    NaN             NaN        8000
```

I use this split function:

```
df[["review","ratings"]] = df["rating"].str.split(expand=True)
```

But I got 'Columns must be same length as key' this type error.

How to split this type of data can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is there is multiple space, not only one at least in one splitted value.

---

You can add `n=1` for split after first space:

```
df[["review","ratings"]] = df["Rating"].str.split(expand=True, n=1)
```

Or use `rsplit` with `n=1` for split by last space:

```
df[["review","ratings"]] = df["Rating"].str.rsplit(expand=True, n=1)
```

Another idea is use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex for get all values before space before float:

```
df[["review","ratings"]] = df["Rating"].str.extract('(.*)\s+(\d+\.\d+)')
```